# A confusion in finding the tangent space of $O(n)$ group.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

The question and the solution is given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

But I could not understand the last 2 paragraphs, why the kernel of $df_{A}$ is as described and why the dimension of the subspace is n choose 2, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Since $A$ is orthogonal, if $C = A^t B$, then $AC = A A^t B = B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author computes that
$$
df_A(B) = (A^tB) + (A^tB)^t.
$$
The kernel of $df_A$ is the literally the set of all matrices $B$ so that $df_A(B) = 0$ (by $0$ I mean the zero matrix).  Hence $B$ is in the kernel of $df_A$ if and only if
$$
(A^tB) + (A^tB)^t =0 \Longrightarrow (A^tB)^t = -A^tB.
$$
This is exactly the definition for $A^tB$ being anti-symmetric.  ($X$ is anti-symmetric if $X^t = -X$, so take $X=A^tB$.)

However, we have assumed that $A \in O(n)$ and so $A^t=A^{-1}$.  So far we have
$$
\mathrm{ker}(df_A) = \{B : A^{-1}B \text{ is anti-symmetric}\}.
$$
Next the author pulls a translation trick, which might be where you got confused.  Note that
$$
\{B : A^{-1}B \text{ is anti-symmetric}\} = \{AC : C \text{ is anti-symmetric}\}
$$
is true by an easy (but omitted) argument.  If $B$ belongs to the left-hand set then $A^{-1}B$ is antisymmetric, and then with $C=A^{-1}B$ we get $AC = AA^{-1}B=B$ belongs to the right.  Reverse this line of thought to get containment in the other direction.

Now for the dimension count.  As $A$ is invertible, multiplication by $A$ yields the map $C \mapsto AC$ which is a bijection from the subspace of all anti-symmetric matrices to the kernel of $df_A$. Hence the dimension of the kernel of $df_A$ is equal to the dimension of the spaces of all anti-symmetric $n \times n$ matrices.  But if a matrix $X = (x_{ij})$ is anti-symmetric, you must have $x_{ji} = -x_{ij}$.  Thus you only have freedom of choice on the lower triangular half of $X$, excluding the diagonal entries as they must be $0$ by anti-symmetry.  Thus, you only have free choices on the entries
$$
x_{21}
$$
$$
x_{31}, x_{32} 
$$
and so on down to
$$
x_{n1}, x_{n2}, \ldots, x_{n,n-1}
$$
How many free parameters is this?  Add them up by rows:
$$
1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots +n-1
$$
which is well-known to equal $\frac{(n-1)n}{2} = \binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry can I ask another question? ......If you agreed .... why in Guillemin and Pollack the writer wrote $O(n) = f^{-1}(I)$?

Comment: Because that's exactly the definition of the orthogonal group:  $A$ is orthogonal if and only if $A^tA=I$.

Comment: How could you elaborate more please, how the preimage of the identity leads to the orthogonal group?